# Quick sort apparently taking O(n^2) when left or right-most element is selected as pivot

Tags: c++, quicksort

So um, I'm trying to learn Quick sort and have implemented the below code for it. However, it seems to run in O(n^2) instead of O(nlogn) when I take leftmost or rightmost element as pivot...

I am unable to figure out what's wrong with my code but I'm most likely making some very basic stupid mistake; can anyone please help and explain me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance! Here's my code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <vector>

   typedef  int64_t  int64;

   int64 numberOfComparisons;

   using namespace std;
   int partitionAroundPivot(vector<int64>& a, int l, int r) {

   numberOfComparisons = numberOfComparisons + (r - l) - 1 ;


   int ppos;
   ppos = l;


   int64 p = a[ppos]; //Gives pivot

   if(ppos != l)
       swap(a[ppos], a[l]);

   int i = l + 1, j;
   for(j = l + 1; j <= r; j++){
       if(a[j]  < p)
       {
           swap(a[j], a[i]); //Swap with leftmost element bigger than pivot, i.e. v[i]
        i++;
       }

   }
   //Now pivot needs to go to its proper place
   swap(a[l], a[i - 1]);

   return ppos; //WRONG, will return l always, need to return i-1

   }
   void quickSort(vector<int64>& a, int l, int r) //Inplace so no return stuff
   {
   if( r - l <= 0)
       return ;



   int pivotPosition =  partitionAroundPivot(a, l, r);
   cout << "Called Qsort with positions  l " <<l << "   r  " << r << " Pivot pos " << pivotPosition <<  endl;

   for (int i = l; i < r; i++)
       cout << a[i] <<"  " ;

   cout << endl;
   quickSort(a, l              , pivotPosition - 1 );
   quickSort(a, pivotPosition + 1  , r                 );

}

int main() {

 vector<int64> x  = {3, 2, 1, 8, 6, 7, 6, 4};
 quickSort(x, 0, x.size() -1);

 return 0;
}
```

Part of the output is below:

```
Called Qsort with positions  l 0   r  9 Pivot pos 0
1  2  3  4  6  10  9  5  7
Pivot: 2
Called Qsort with positions  l 1   r  9 Pivot pos 1
2  3  4  6  10  9  5  7
Pivot: 3
```

EDIT: Part of the reason why I asked this was because I am supposed to calculate the number of comparisons done in total theoritically, and I simply used a (size of subarray at each partition call - 1) as the value (the actual ones will be different, I know since only part of the comparisons actually happen). This is seen in the numberOfComparisons variable above.

Now the thing is, for sorting 100 numbers, all from 1-100, none unique and mostly random, it shows the number of computations as 4851, that's close to 100*99/2 aka n*(n-1)/2 where n = 100. This led me to believe that it's doing O(n^2) time. Is this correct...?

EDIT2: I was being so stupid after all. The partitionAroundPivot was always returning l aka the first position of the subarray, resulting in one of the splits being a zero length subarray and another, the rest of the array. I need to pass back the position where a[l] actually goes and not l; i-1 in this case. Lesson learnt, I guess.

Thank you very much for the help, guys!

Comment: The worst-case time complexity of quick sort is O(n^2) Try with some random data as input.

Comment: That's what Quicksort does. Every time you pick the smallest or largest element, or something close to the smallest or largest element, as the pivot, one pass will make very little progress. That's why taking the first or last element of the array as the pivot isn't recommended _at all_.

Comment: @gnasher729 Why do you assume that that first or the last elements of an array will always be the smallest/biggest ?

Comment: @MikeCAT But isn't Quick Sort supposed to give O(n^2) complexity only if the array is already sorted? EDIT: Also, for {3, 5, 1, 4 , 2, 8, 7}; it is throwing "2  1  3  4  5  7  8" as the output, so something else might be wrong as well...

Comment: I am sorry, bit "this code I call quicksort is broken in many ways, help" is not a good SO question: and that is what your problem seems to boil down to.  Details like "It also dies not work" make what would be an acceptable answer pretry vague.

Answer (score 2):

Qucksort is O(n log n) but in average, it is O(n^2) in worst case and O(nlogn) in best-case. The most important aspect to get a good efficiency is to select a good pivot.

In your program, you have selected one of the worst pivots because if you select the first or the last one, in case of ordered (or reverse-ordered) vectors, your algorithm is in the worst case efficiency.

This is why you have to think about your algorithm to select the pivot. One of the most used methods is to select the median of three, for example, the first, middle and last elements. Thus, you algorithm applied to a ordered vector is O(nlogn).

UPDATE: The complexity is determined by a profile of growth, not a specific case. In fact, you could have a very high value for a particular size of the problem, while the profile increases more smoothly when the problem size becomes very large. Before checking anything, run the program with several individual values reaching a very large n.

Comment: Yup, it seems that way. But um, I'm really sorry for not being clear on my question. I edited it above to add why I feel it's running in O(n^2) due to the number of comparisons made...

Comment: Nope, you can't conclude that. Remember that O(4851) is O(1), but obviously your method isn't O(1). You simply can't work from a single number to a big-O value.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, I should go revise growth of functions again, haha. Thank you very much for the insights!